# Mapbox - styling color of "off the map" area

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using the Mapbox library for React Native. When the user is zoomed out with a pitch ("3D mode"), they can see "off the map". This "off the map" colour is the same as the "on map" land colour and it doesn't look great. I was wondering how I could change the style/colour of "off the map", or if there's another nice way to handle this. Thanks!

[image: screenshot of map]

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on what style you're using. I believe all the styles take the color of the land (which is why you're seeing the green).

If you create your own style from scratch, you can adjust the `background` layer to reflect the color you'd like to see.

[image: studio gif]

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm using a custom style based on the "Mapbox Basic Template" without any new layers added, but the "background" layer also affects the colour of the general land mass.

Comment: Is this how you mean? This doesn't seem to have any effect, i.e. "background" overlaps and is always on top of "background duplicate". https://i.imgur.com/GzpAkoL.png

Comment: Another solution might be to allow the map to "loop" vertically (in the same way as when you scroll horizontally). Do you know if this is possible? Thanks! @BDD

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by loop. Do your users need to do 3D? You could always disable the ability to do pitch.